# How to rollback the first transaction and not rollback the new transaction?

Tags: java, transactions, rollback, jta

I have a method that save a object but I need consumes an API and save their return. If the API return is "not authorized", I need rollback the transaction but I want preserve the return.

E.g.

```
@Resource
private SessionContext context;

@Transactional
public Invoice createSale(SaleDTO saleDTO) {
    this.dao.save(saleDTO);

    Send send = this.context.getBusinessObject(Send.class);
    Invoice invoice = this.send.send(saleDTO);

    if (invoice.isAuthorized()) {            
        invoice.setSale(saleDTO);

        return invoice;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}

public class Send implements Serializable {
 @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
 private Invoice send(SaleDTO saleDTO) {
     Invoice invoice;

     ...

     this.dao.save(invoice);

     return invoice;
 }
}
```

When I thrown the IllegalArgumentException, the invoice is not saved. I need save it.

Answer (score 2):

Annotating a private method, or even a public method called from another method of the same class, can't work.

Transactional handling is based on proxies.

A transaction can only be started if you call a transactional method on another bean, injected in the current bean, so that the transactional proxy wrapping the other bean intercepts the call and starts a transaction.

Read https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#tx-decl-explained. You don't seem to use Spring, but the way it works in Java EE is the same.